# how do i get back textbox value after form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i want to get back or post back textbox value after form has been submit it is necessary because of user's must be see what values he or her typed in the textbox?

```
function getComboA(sel) { 
var cname=document.getElementById("cname");
var input_val = document.getElementById("cname").value;
name.action = "searchreceivable.php?cname="+input_val+"";
name.submit();
}

<form name="name" id="name"><input class="input_field" type="text"
name="cname" id="cname" onchange="getComboA();"></form>
```

Now Problem is Solved This Is My Final Code So It Will Retain Textbox Value Once Form Submitted

```
function getComboA(sel) { 
var cname=document.getElementById("cname");
var input_val = document.getElementById("cname").value;
name.action = "searchreceivable.php?cname="+input_val+"";
name.submit();
}

<form name="name" id="name"><input class="input_field" type="text"
name="cname" id="cname" onchange="getComboA();" 
value="<?php echo $txtVal=$_GET['cname']; ?>"></form>
```

Comment: use `onsumbit` attribute for `form`

Comment: Don't call your form "name". Also your form will not submit until you leave the field

Answer (score 0):

```
function getComboA(sel) { 
var cname=document.getElementById("cname");
var input_val = document.getElementById("cname").value;
form.action = "searchreceivable.php?cname="+input_val;
form.submit();
}
```

The code is to be done on searchreceivable.php-

```
<?php
$txtVal=$_GET['cname'];
?>
```

Comment: prateek shukla any example?

Comment: @FarhanAziz would you mind putting the solution as an answer to this thread to help out others who might experience the problem that you had here in the future.

Comment: And then I would not have to read the question, I seek for unanswered question and hit this one. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need it to store via javascript? Maybe you can just do something like:

```
<input class="input_field" type="text"
name="cname" id="cname" onchange="getComboA();" value="<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>">
```

Comment: still input textbox blank after form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mark this question jQuery and you want to send data to the server onchange, then I suggest

```
$(function() {
  $("#cname").on("change",function() {
    $.get("searchreceivable.php?cname="+$(this).val(),function(data) {
      $("#result").html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

using

```
<form>
  <input id="cname" class="input_field" type="text" value=""/>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```